Why were the three not recommended as Special Grade sorcerers?
At the end of season 1 of Jujutsu Kaisen, Mei Mei and Aoi Todo recommend Yuji Itadori, Nobara Kugisaki, Megumi Fushiguro, Maki Zen'in, and one other (Toge Inumaki?) to be first-grade Jujutsu sorcerers.
However, the 'main cast,' Yuji, Nobara, and Megumi, had already

killed one special-grade each (Yuji and Nobara killed the two brothers working with Geto) and I believe that the special-grade Megumi killed was stronger than the one that required Yuji to switch with Sukuna earlier in the show. That special-grade was strong enough to (temporarily) kill Yuji). At least, Megumi said he was several grades stronger.

Earlier in the show, it was said (I think by Panda) that any sorcerer would be able to defeat any curse of the same grade. That is, a second-grade sorcerer should, in theory, be able to defeat any second-grade curse. The same would hold true for the other grades.
So if

the three had already killed special-grades,

why were they not recommended as special-grade sorcerers?
